# CSS - How to set an elements height as a % of a container with auto height?

Tags: css

Suppose I have a text block inside a container, and the height of the container is set to auto. So, its height changes to dynamically fit however much text is present.

Suppose then that I have an image also in the container, floating beside the text and I would like it to scale to some percentage of the container's height.

```
<div class="container">
<img style="height: 50%; float: left;" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/logocss.gif" width="95" height="84"><br>
<p> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
</div>
```

If I set 'container' height to say, 500px, the image will scale to a height of 250px. If I set the height of 'container' to auto however, the image's height does not scale to 50% of its parent's height. It does not scale at all.

If possible, I would also like to set a min-height restriction on 'container' in the event of no text in the container, but this is not a high priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily by flex css

Try following on parent div

```
display:flex
Flex-direction:row
```

Now create 2 divs within parent div and put image in one and text in another and add  following to css of each div

```
flex:1
```

Now you divs are of equal width and aligned side by side. Now say you want to adjust your image you  can do it easily by giving padding or margin top or using flex again on this div.

Hope it helps

Comment: I'll try to see if I can get this to work, but I was hoping for a solution with more browser support. W3Schools says this is not supported by IE9 or earlier. Thanks, though.

Comment: All modern browsers work with this though, dont forget to add webkit properties, tick the answer  if this helps

Comment: So I got the flex to work where it gives me two columns of equal width, however my image is then stretched horizontally (which I don't want), and I can't figure out how to stretch it vertically to a % of the height of the container.

Comment: Perhaps read some more about flex? See justify content property once

Comment: Okay, I couldn't get it to stretch to a percentage, but it did fix the main problem I was having. Maybe I'll figure out a solution later, but for now this will do. Thanks.